# WebGL dynamic model manipulation

Tags: dynamic, 3d, webgl, modeling, solidworks

My goal is to be able to create a 3D model in a Cad package  (Ie. Solidworks) with parameters that are designed to be changed by the user.
I want to be able to take that model and integrate it into a web browser, and then pass variables from some kind of UI into the model to change its parameters and hence its form.

As a simple example: a cylinder where the user can select how tall it is using a slider.
*(The cylinder would be derived from cad software, rather than webgl CylinderGeometry )*

At this stage I know very little about Webgl, and how I to achieve this result so pointing me in the right direction would be a huge help.

Comment: The only way I can think to do it is to use something like [OpenJsCad](http://joostn.github.com/OpenJsCad/)
And somehow convert a dynamic cad file from OpenSCad or even Solidworks
Is there any way to convert to OpenJsCad?

Answer (score 1):

You can build an HTTP service [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api). The service would receive HTTP requests with 'parameters that are designed to be changed', process it correspondingly. Then it'd launch SolidWorks, load a model, change parameters and rebuild. After that you should decide a data format which would be sent to browser:

- STL, OBJ - tessellation, colors, no texture info. Can be easily parsed by JavaScript
- If you use SceneJS for WebGL you can generate proper JSON scene on the server side